# Multi tab event sharing with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

My scenario is:
Multiple copies of same web application is open on multiple tab of same browser. I go to one of the tab. I click on a button present of page and on click of that button it registers focus event on window.

```
$('#btn').click(function(event){
if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) {
  document.addEventListener("focusin", onFocus,false);
} else {
  window.addEventListener("focus", onFocus,false);
}

function onFocus(){$
  //Reload Page if logged out$
  window.location.reload();$
};$
```

It is expected that when I switch to other tabs and page should get reloaded.

Problem is that page on other is not reloading.

Comment: You are looking at cross tab communication. Look at a library called postaljs which has a plugin for federated communication that can send messages between tabs and windows. Might be a good place to start.

Comment: I think you need web sockets. Take a look at http://socket.io/

Comment: Let me reframe my question. If I register event at start of page load only then it's work as intended. But if register event at on based on some other event then it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If I add listener at page load then it works.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) { // check for Internet Explorer
    document.addEventListener("focusin", onFocus,false);
  } else {
    window.addEventListener("focus", onFocus,false);
  }
  return true;
});
```